# GA4 Service Account: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile

Tags: google-analytics, authorization, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to do a very dumb and obvious thing - set up a page on my website that shows the 10 most visited blog posts for the last 30 days. I want to use GA4 data for this. This is what I did:

1. Created a service account with View permission (https://console.cloud.google.com/).

[image]

2. Analytics API is enabled.

[image]

3. Service account added as a Viewer into GA4 property access settings.

[image]

4. I'm using Nest.js back-end with the latest googleapis npm package. Here's the code:

```js
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: '/home/...service-account.json',
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
})
```

I get `User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.` error.

What do I do wrong, what have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Data API has to be enabled and used to access GA4 reporting. There's `@google-analytics/data` package for that.